# CXF SOAP service preserve space

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have CXF soap web service.

```
@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com....MyWs", serviceName="MySrv")
public class MyWsImpl implements MyWs {
    @Override
    public List<MyModel> get(String customer) {
        List<MyModel> models = ...;
        return models;
    }
}
```

There is a filed in MyModel that can be a space (`" "`), but the parser trims the value and it's serialized as `<mySpaceVal></mySpaceVal>` wile I want `<mySpaceVal> </mySpaceVal>`

How can I do that?

I tried to add

```
@XmlAttribute(name="space", namespace="xml")
public final static String space = "preserve";
```

to MyModel so the parser can add xml:space="preserve" attribute.
But it adds a namespace `ns3="xml"` and displays the attribute as `ns3:space="preserve"` and the element is displayed as an empty string instead of `" "`

Comment: Can you insert &nbsp; instead?  Having a space character there is a terrible design but if that's what you're stuck with you may need to use the escape sequence instead.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks for the response, but it doesen't work. The framework escapes the string and I end up with `<mySpaceVal>&amp;nbsp;</mySpaceVal>`

Comment: That is not unexpected, unfortunately.  Is there anything else you could put there?  The space character is tough to have by itself.  How about a "sentry" value like "-s-" or some other character?

Comment: @stdunbar Unfortunately this value comes from another system. It can be some normal string like "123" but " " is also valid and I have to send it to the client of the web service as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your string value in `<![CDATA[]]>` section using `jaxb` adapter:

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CDATAXmlAdapter.class)
public final static String space = "...";

private static class CDATAXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(final String value) throws Exception {
        // you may want to apply additional value escaping to avoid
        // CDATA nesting problem
        return "<![CDATA[" + value + "]]>";
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(final String value) throws Exception {
        // If you expect that server will send CDATA as well
        // then you need to strip CDATA from value
        return value;
    }
}
```